# Server-side JavaScript --> Simple Dynamic Site

Tags: programming-languages, content-management-system, server-side, serverside-javascript

Note: This is not about the merits/demerits of SSJS

I am only asking if you think it is possible to create a simple dynamic site strictly using some form of SSJS. I am in no position to do any arguing (0 programming experience) -- I can only give you the benefit of some of the most interesting tutorials and information I ran across yesterday while doing some intensive Googling. I'm posting those links here in hopes that someone will browse through them and have light bulbs go off in their head.

**Here are some of those links:** (hold on -- I can only post one at a time)

1) NodeJS Tutorial w/ CouchDB & HAML: http://www.robsearles.com/2010/05/28/nodejs-tutorial-with-couchdb-and-haml-erdnodeflips/

**Do you think it is possible to create a simple dynamic site strictly using some form of SSJS?**

Comment: The answer is obviously yes -- it is all in the links you posted. But this is not a forum, you might want to take this discussion somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

2) Blog rolling with mongoDB, express and Node.js: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

Comment: Going to add the rest via comments:

3) Create a web app with Node.js: http://boldr.net/create-a-web-app-with-node

Comment: 4) Nodejs. I just have to use it for something: http://www.hawksworx.com/journal/2010/02/15/nodejs-i-just-have-to-use-it-for-something/